# getting "NameError: name 'Twitter' is not defined" when using google cloud platform, but not when run locally

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, twitter, google-cloud-platform

[Here's the link to the repository for my code](https://github.com/aayub98/twittercountdown).
Here's the main file that has the issue if you don't wanna gander into the rest of the repo.

```
import yaml
from twitter import *
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import time
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)
# sys.path.append(".")

#the part where you figure out how many days are left
def calculate_dates():
    now = datetime.now()
    gradDay = datetime(2020, 5, 15)
    return (gradDay - now.today()).days + 1

# new_status = 'happy ' + str(calculate_dates()) + ' days until grad'
new_status = 'test3'

with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.safe_load(ymlfile)

#this is the method i used when it was just the flask app running locally
# while True:
#     if (datetime.now().hour is 9 and datetime.now().minute is 0 and datetime.now().second is 0):
#         twitter = Twitter(auth = OAuth(cfg['twitterkeys']['access_token_key'],
#                   cfg['twitterkeys']['access_token_secret'],
#                   cfg['twitterkeys']['consumer_key'],
#                   cfg['twitterkeys']['consumer_secret']))
#         results = twitter.statuses.update(status = new_status)
#         time.sleep(5)
# # print("updated status: %s" % new_status)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "hello"

@app.route("/tweet")
def tweet():
    twitter = Twitter(auth = OAuth(cfg['twitterkeys']['access_token_key'],
                  cfg['twitterkeys']['access_token_secret'],
                  cfg['twitterkeys']['consumer_key'],
                  cfg['twitterkeys']['consumer_secret']))
    results = twitter.statuses.update(status = new_status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Until now, I've been tweeting how many days are left until I graduate manually every day just for fun (and to remind myself to have fun before I graduate), and a friend suggested I automate it. At first, I was running the Flask app on my computer and had something in my code that would just tweet out the days left every day at 9am, but I wanted to put it on GCP so I wouldn't have to run it locally forever. When I ran the Flask app locally, everything was fine, and it'll tweet it out.

Now, I have set up this Python Flask app so that when traveling to the /tweet route, it'll tweet out how many days are left until graduation at Virginia Tech. On GCP, I've made a cron job that'll travel to /tweet out at the right time to send out the tweet (currently in the repo it's not set to 9am because I was testing it out, and that's when I found the error).

When the time for execution for the cron job comes around, I get an error that it failed.

```
NameError: name 'Twitter' is not defined

        at tweet (/srv/main.py:38)
        at dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1935)
        at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1949)
        at reraise (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39)
        at handle_user_exception (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1820)
        at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1951)
        at wsgi_app (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:2446)
```

Originally, I had my virtual environment named "twitter" so through another thread online about a similar issue, I thought it might've confused the twitter package with something in there. Renaming it didn't help. I tried reinstalling the twitter package which also didn't help. Not sure what to try out next. I don't think it's anything to do with how I set up Flask because if I run this version locally and travel to /tweet, it sends out a tweet.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I realized I hadn't followed the "pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt" command to copy the libraries into a lib folder, just tried it and it didn't change my error.

P.S. it's 69 days until grad

Comment: Where and how are you deploying this on GCP? App Engine? It seems like your dependencies in your `requirements.txt` file are not getting installed.

Comment: @DustinIngram I installed the Google Cloud SDK and followed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env

Comment: Dustin means that in your requirements.txt file you should include all the libraries you would like to use on your app engine application.  eg searching here for [twitter](https://pypi.org/project/twitter/) and doing the same for any other library.

Comment: Try to deploy your code from a clean environment without installing any library in local (from a clean compute engine for example) and remove the versions from your requirements, I encountered similar issues in the past and this worked for me. Let me know if this works for you!